# Deserializing JSON using custom deserializer with JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "MobileSiteContents": {
    "au/en": [
      "http://www.url1.com",
      "http://www.url2.com",

    ],
    "cn/zh": [
      "http://www.url2643.com",

    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize it into an `IEnumerable` of classes that look like this:

```
public class MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem : ContentSectionItem
{
    public string[] Urls { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ContentSectionItem
{
    public string Culture { get; set; }
}
```

Is that possible?
I realise I will probably need to use a Custom JsonConverter for this, but can't find any examples.

I started writing a method to convert using `JObject.Parse` but not sure if this is the correct / most efficient route to go down:

```
public IEnumerable<MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem> Parse(string json)
{
    var jobject = JObject.Parse(json);

    var result = new List<MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem>();

    foreach (var item in jobject.Children())
    {
        var culture = item.Path;
        string[] urls = new[] { "" }; //= this is the part I'm having troble with here...

        result.Add(new MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem { Culture = culture, Urls = urls });
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Here are the corrections you need to make:

1. You're iterating over children of the top-level object expecting to get data that is actually in an object one level further down.  You need to navigate to the *value* of the `MobileSiteContents` property and iterate over the children of that.
2. When you take the `Children()` of the `JObject`, use the overload that lets you cast them to `JProperty` objects; that will make it much easier to extract the data you want.
3. Get the `culture` from the `Name` of the `JProperty` item
4. To get the `urls`, get the `Value` of the `JProperty` item and use `ToObject<string[]>()` to convert it to a string array.

Here is the corrected code:

```
public IEnumerable<MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem> Parse(string json)
{
    var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

    var result = new List<MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem>();

    foreach (var item in jObject["MobileSiteContents"].Children<JProperty>())
    {
        var culture = item.Name;
        string[] urls = item.Value.ToObject<string[]>();

        result.Add(new MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem { Culture = culture, Urls = urls });
    }

    return result;
}
```

If you like terse code, you can reduce this to a "one-liner":

```
public IEnumerable<MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem> Parse(string json)
{
    return JObject.Parse(json)["MobileSiteContents"]
        .Children<JProperty>()
        .Select(prop => new MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem
        {
            Culture = prop.Name,
            Urls = prop.Value.ToObject<string[]>()
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""MobileSiteContents"": {
                ""au/en"": [
                    ""http://www.url1.com"",
                    ""http://www.url2.com"",
                ],
                ""cn/zh"": [
                    ""http://www.url2643.com"",
                ]
            }
        }";

        foreach (MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem item in Parse(json))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Culture);
            foreach (string url in item.Urls)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  " + url);
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem> Parse(string json)
    {
        return JObject.Parse(json)["MobileSiteContents"]
            .Children<JProperty>()
            .Select(prop => new MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem()
            {
                Culture = prop.Name,
                Urls = prop.Value.ToObject<string[]>()
            })
            .ToList();
    }

    public class MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem : ContentSectionItem
    {
        public string[] Urls { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class ContentSectionItem
    {
        public string Culture { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
au/en
  http://www.url1.com
  http://www.url2.com
cn/zh
  http://www.url2643.com
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried this using Json.Net and works fine.

```
public IEnumerable<MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem> Parse(string json)
{
     dynamic jobject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

     var result = new List<MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem>();

     var urls = new List<string>();
     foreach (var item in jobject.MobileSiteContents)
     {
         var culture = item.Name;
         foreach(var url in item.Value)
            urls.Add(url.Value);

         result.Add(new MobileSiteContentsContentSectionItem { Culture = culture, Urls = urls.ToArray() });
     }

     return result;
}
```